# Integration on sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ for $d$ large -- Change of variables

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials, spherical-geometry

I'm trying to integrate a function over two vectors which lie on the surface of the unit sphere in D dimensions. The function depends only on the difference between the two vectors, and their dot product. Can I make a change of variables to simplify this integral? Thanks for your help.

\begin{equation}
\int \int d^D \mathbf{u} \ d^D \mathbf{v} \ f(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \delta(\|\mathbf{u}\|^2-1)\delta(\|\mathbf{v}\|^2-1)
\end{equation}

Comment: From the form of your integral, it appears $f$ depends on the **difference** $\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}$, and not just their **distance** $|\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}|$, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, the integral actually depends on the signed difference. I will update the post to clarify. Thanks @WillieWong

Comment: As @Josiah mentioned in his answer, you have that $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} = 1 - \frac12 (\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})\cdot(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})$ so the two arguments of your function $f$ are not independent. Next, given $\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}$ with length < 2, **and** a unit vector $\omega \perp (\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}$, you can solve for $$ \mathbf{u} = \sqrt{1 - |\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}|^2 / 4} \omega + \frac12 (\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}) $$ and similarly $\mathbf{v}$. So you can reparametrize the the product of the two unit spheres (a $2(D-1)$ dimensional manifold) by the product of the...

Comment: .. $D$ dimensional ball $(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})$ against the $D-2$ dimensional sphere ($\omega$). The integral against the latter vanishes and just give you its surface area (with the appropriate radius). The integral against the former factor has to be evaluated, with a carefully computed Jacobian. In the generality that you are seeking that's the best that one can do.

Comment: This is just what I'm looking for. Thanks again @WillieWong

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** The below answer addresses a separate question than that in the updated question. @WillieWong's comments above are most relevant to the question when the function depends on the difference $\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}$ instead of the distance.

'The function depends only on the distance between the two vectors, and their dot product.'

In other words the function can be taken to only be a function of the dot product, or distance (since $\|x-y\|^2=2-2\langle x,y \rangle$, for $x,y$ on the sphere).

One can expand the function $f$ into its Gegenbauer expansion $f(\langle x,y \rangle)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k C_{k}(\langle x,y \rangle)$ where  $C_{k}(t)$ are Gegenbauer polynomials. Assuming the convergence is good enough to allow exchanging the sum and integral, the addition formula gives  $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k C_{k}(\langle x,y \rangle) dx dy=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\dim V_k}a_k b_k \left(\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}  Y_{m,k}(x)dx \right)^2,$$

where spherical harmonics are denoted $Y_{m,k}$, $V_k$ is the finite-dimensional space of spherical harmonics of degree $k$, and $b_k$ are constants (which depend on how one normalizes the spherical harmonics $Y_{m,k}$). This reduces the double integral to a sum of integrals. It is not clear if $dx$ denotes the surface measure on the sphere. If so, then all terms with $k\geq 1$ are zero, meaning the integral is just the constant term in the Gegenbauer expansion of $f$.

Comment: Isn't "computing the constant term of the Gegenbauer expansion" basically just computing the integral asked for?

Comment: Of course, if the measure is surface measure (normalized to be a probability measure). But it is much simpler to expand the function into Gegenbauer polynomials and compute the value of the integral this way (than computing the ugly multi-dimensional integral). Computing the constant term in this case requires a single integral over $[-1,1]$. Either way, it is a simplification as compared to viewing the integral naively.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. My point is that the action "expand the function into Gegenbauer polynomials" contains, as one of its sub-actions, "compute the value of the integral in question"; so we have a chicken and egg problem: if the OP already has a way to quickly/easily compute the coefficients of the Gegenbauer polynomial expansion, presumably the question would not have been asked!

Comment: I do not see any other way to answer this question without additional information. The OP does not mention being aware of the orthogonal polynomials and how they relate to integrating over the sphere. If @ostrich responds it will be more clear.

Comment: With that I am in total agreement.

Comment: I apologize, as Willie correctly pointed out, I meant to say the integral depends on the _difference_ between u,v. I hadn't thought of decomposing into spherical harmonics, @JosiahPark, thanks. I will think more about it.

Comment: @ostrich458 The clarification is addressed in the answer above now. IIt is possible to remove the answer if it is not longer relevant.

Comment: It is my mistake. Thanks again for your thoughtful answer.