# |Evaluating integral on $ \mathbb S^{d-1}$

Tags: integration, spherical-geometry

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \int_{\mathbb S^{d-1}} \exp \bigg(-\frac{(1+x\cdot y)^2}{\|x+y\|^2} \bigg) \ dx $$

for $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$. Does anyone know a solution or an approach I might take?

Comment: Is it possible that the $(x+y)^2$ in the denominator should be $|x+y|^2$ instead?

Comment: If so, write $|x+y|^2=2+2\langle x,y \rangle$ and just use the procedure from your previous question (find the first term in the Gegenbauer expansion of the function by integrating with respect to the measure which the Gegenbauer polynomials are orthogonal with respect to: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GegenbauerPolynomial.html).

Comment: Yes, sloppy notation. I'll fix the post.

Comment: I see. Where $(1-t^2)^{\frac{d-2}{2}}$ is the measure? And perhaps a minus sign in the exponential?

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 performs $\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{e}} \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{d+1}{2};\frac{1}{16}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)$ , where $  \, _0\tilde{F}_1$ is the regularizied hypergeometric function,for the integral suggested by Josiah Park in his above comment, .

Comment: The usual expansion is $f(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \hat{f_n} \frac{n+\lambda}{\lambda}C_n(t)$, where $\lambda=\frac{d-1}{2}$. The coefficient $\hat{f}_0=\frac{\Gamma(\lambda+1)}{\Gamma(\lambda+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}\int\limits_{-1}^1f(t)(1-t^2)^{\lambda-\frac{1}{2}}dt$. So that formula should account for any missing constant. This gives value $\frac{2(2-\frac{2}{e})}{\pi}$ for $d=3$.

Comment: $C_0$ is a Gegenbauer polynomial. But it is the constant function $1$, so it does not play in.

Comment: If this is the motivation for the previous question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346280/integration-on-sphere-mathbbsd-1-for-d-large-change-of-variables), it is worth noting this function  depends only on distances, which is why it can be reduced to a one-dimensional integral.

Comment: One last thing: Mathematica can evaluate the above integral. However, I am interested in the more general case where $(1+x \cdot y)^2$ is replaced by $(a+x\cdot y)^2$ for some constant $a$. Mathematica doesn't seem to be able to evaluate this integral. Do you have any tips?

Comment: The motivation for the previous question was a different integral, but in both cases I was hoping to reduce the dimension of the integral.

Comment: Do you want asymptotics as $a$ tends to some value? Otherwise it is not clear that there should even be an elementary expression for the integral.

Comment: I see. Ultimately I would like to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\lambda \int_{-\infty}^{-b} dh \int_{\mathbb S^{d-1}} dx \exp\bigg( - \frac{(h+x\cdot y)^2 \lambda}{\|x+y\|^2} \bigg)$, (where I use a saddle point approximation for large $d$ to integrate over $\lambda$), but I wanted to post a simpler question in the forum.

Comment: This has already helped me quite a bit, though. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand the integral as written (the variables do not line up with the arguments in the integrand). Also there is a small mistake in the expansion above. This expansion is for the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. The value of the integral there is still for $\mathbb{S}^{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it too quickly. Is it clear now?

Comment: It looks as if you are best estimating it (while still using the expansion).

Comment: Ok, I will give it a shot. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Josiah Park: Deleting  comments is not  good practice.

Comment: @user64494 My apologies. I noticed there was some inconsistencies between the choice of notation in the integral your comment above referred to and the one which appears later. I've mentioned the fact that the second formula is for $\mathbb{S}^d$ (the one now removed was for $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$).

Comment: @ostrich458 I think the value of the integral evaluated above is for surface measure normalized to be a probability measure, so you may have to multiply by the surface area to get the value you are interested in.